# How to connect Linux network namespace with other VM using internal network?

Tags: linux, networking, network-namespaces

I have two Virtual Machnes (VM) in Virtualbox connected with internal network. On the first one I have network namespace named n0. I want to connect this namespace to network interface and finally connect it with the second Virtual Machine (VM2) using internal connection.
Network example:

[image: Network example]

As you can see, I want to have connection between 192.168.127.2/24 and 192.168.127.1/24.

My attempt to solve this problem using openvswitch (not working):

```
sudo ovs-vsctl add-br br0 
sudo ifconfig br0 up
sudo ip link add veth type veth peer name veth-br 
sudo ip link set veth netns ns0
sudo ifconfig veth-br up
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth-br
sudo ip netns exec ns0 ip addr add 192.168.127.2/24 dev veth
sudo ip netns exec ns0 ip link set veth up
sudo ip addr add 192.168.127.3/24 dev br0
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
```

Could you please help me with this?
Do you see how can I improve my solution to work properly?

Extended network topology:

[image]

There is a working connection between ns1 and ns0, but I try to connect ns1 with 192.168.127.1/24. To do this, besides the connection between 192.168.127.2/24 and 192.168.127.1/24, I need to add static routing but I can't do it. I was planning on trying to do this using openvswitch and commands:

```
sudo ip netns exec ns1 route add -net 192.168.127.0/24 gw 192.168.1.10 dev wlan1
sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.127.2 dev br0
```

where br0 is openvswitch - bridge.

Comment: What kind of VMs do you have? Docker? LXC? Vmware? Virtualbox? Something else? What kind of networks does your VM environment to create?

Comment: I changed my post and add informations you mentioned.

Comment: Virtualbox has somewhat funny networking, and I have no idea how compatible it is with network namespaces inside the VM. First thing I'd try is to make an additional internal network adapter with command line options per VM, and move that into the namespace inside the VM, and see if that works. Second thing I'd try is to make a macvlan inside the network namespace slaved to the internal network adapter. All of this may or may not work.

Comment: When I move the internal network interface to the namespace inside the virtual machine, I have a connection between 192.168.127.1 and 192.168.127.2 but I still need to make this connection using openvswitch.

Comment: Why do you need to make it with openvsswitch?

Comment: To explain I edited the post. Sorry for changes but this is the best way explain you where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

(Making changes to the question is the accepted way to add clarifications, so that's totally fine)

But I still don't see why you need openvswitch. The way I would do it is (note how I represent network segments as lines, showing the segments clearly is important in network design):

```
192.168.1.*/24                      192.168.127.*/24
   WLAN                                Internal
     :                                    |
     :  +------------------------------+  |  +----------------------+
     :  | +--------------------------+ |  |  |                      |
     +--|-|- wlan0 192.168.1.1       | |  +--|- 192.168.127.1 eth0  |
     :  | |                      ns1 | |  |  |                      |
     :  | +--------------------------+ |  |  |                  VM2 |
     :  |                              |  |  +----------------------+
     :  | +--------------------------+ |  |  
     +--|-|- wlan1 192.168.1.10      | |  |  
     :  | |                          | |  |
     :  | |  macvlan0 192.168.127.2 -|-|--+
     :  | |  (to eth0)           ns0 | |  |
     :  | +--------------------------+ |  |
     :  |                              |  |
     :  |        eth0 192.168.127.4 ---|--+
     :  |                              |  |
     :  |                          VM1 |  |
        +------------------------------+
```

So VM1, ns0 and VM2 can see each other on the virtualbox internal network. Assuming that *is* your goal, I am still not entirely clear on that.

So you make a `macvlan` with `eth0` as master, and move it inside `ns0`:

```
# In VM1, main namespace
ip link add macvlan0 link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip link set macvlan0 netns ns0
ip -n ns0 addr add 192.168.127.2/24 dev macvlan0
ip -n ns0 link set macvlan0 up
ip -n ns0 show macvlan0
```

Or you just use the DHCP server on the Internal network to let the macvlan pick up its IP, running a DHCP client etc. There are various ways to make the above permanent, depending on your distro.

That solution depends on macvlans working with virtualbox internal networking (which they may or may not; as I wrote, virtualbox networking is weird). If it doesn't work, next thing I'd try is to scrap the internal network segment, and try a virtualbox bridged one instead.

No openvswitch needed, and I don't see actually any easy way to combine openvswitch with virtualbox internal networking.

So if you only want to use openvswitch because you read about it somewhere and you found it interesting, then maybe you don't have to use it here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You're right, I don't have to use openvswitch, but that was my only idea to fix the problem - as you can see, it doesn't work anyway.
I am trying to use macvlan as you suggested but now I have no connection between 192.168.127.2 and 192.168.127.1, only 192.168.127.4 is connected to 192.168.127.1 - is that correct?
Moreover, there is no connection between ns0 and default netns.

Comment: What is more I can't replace the internal network to bridged because later I will change VM1 to physical Access Point.

Comment: Now I am totally confused - how do you want to "change VM1 to a physical access point", and how does this require the current configuration of VM1?

Comment: Okay, sorry, now I've completely complicated it - it doesn't matter at this point.
Now it's just an experiment that can help me create the final environment.
I want to communicate ns1 using wlan connection to VM2, but as you can see, I have a problem with connection between ns0 and VM2. 
Once again - sorry for complicate it.

Comment: So, could you help me with connect ns0 with VM2 using macvlan and set routing 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.127.2?